# Table with pictures: rotating titles (of the row)

Tags: floats, diagrams, rotating, landscape

I'm trying to do a table with pictures on a landscape page but I have few problems. Firstly, I want to rotate the titles ("row" in the picture) of the first column and center it with the row. After that, I would add a small line below each titles ("row" and "column"). Do you think the better way to do that It's just to use the underline command ? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
& column & column & column\\
row &
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image}\\
row &
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image}\\
row &
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image}\\
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption for the whole figure}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure*}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: A quick picture to illustrate what I want]

Comment: Please make a complete MWE from your code.

Comment: Sorry first time here. Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    & column & column & column\\
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{row} &
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,valign=c]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,valign=c]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,valign=c]{example-image-c}\\
    \addlinespace
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{row} &
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,valign=c]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,valign=c]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,valign=c]{example-image-c}\\
    \addlinespace
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{row} &
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,valign=c]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,valign=c]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,valign=c]{example-image-c}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption for the whole figure}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure*}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot, I tried a lot of different things but didn't achieve a good result !

Comment: @Romain, when you have enough reputation (15), you can vote answer (by clicking up pen at top left side of answer). if you like answer, you can accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-). happy tex-ing!